# Congruence modulo a power of two

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let $a \geq 3$. Let $2^a \mid c^2-1$. 
By simple divisibility rules I get

$$c \equiv 1 \mod 2^a \quad \text{or} \quad c \equiv -1 \mod 2^a  $$

or

$$c \equiv 1 \mod 2^{a-1},\quad  c \equiv  -1 \mod 2 $$

or

$$c \equiv -1 \mod 2^{a-1},\quad  c \equiv  1 \mod 2 $$

Can you explain me how to obtain the following congruence:

$$
c \; \equiv \; \pm 1 + 2^{a-1} \mod 2^a 
$$
??

Comment: Looks to me as if you copied the problem wrong. Consider $a=3$, so your congruences are modulo $8$. There is no number $c$ such that $c^2+1$ is divisible by eight, try all the numbers from $0$ to $7$ to check this. Maybe you meant $c^2-1$?

Comment: The congruence $c^2+1\equiv 0\pmod{2^a}$ is not interesting,since $c^2+1\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ or $c^2+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @Lubin: sorry for the typo, it was $c^2-1$!!

Comment: I don't quite understand the flow of your logic. Are you trying to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem or something? Remember that CRT gives information about the residue classes modulo $ab$ in terms of residue classes modulo $a$ (resp. $b$) when $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: Both answers point out that your conclusion is not completely right; the value $c=1$ is a solution, and it is not congruent to $1+2^{a-1}$ modulo $2^a$.

Comment: @Lubin: I haven't said that $c=1$ is not a solution, there are 4 solutions up to congruence. My question was about how to obtain the relation at the bottom of my message.

Comment: Well,it’s not important in any way, but your last congruence as written seems to forbid the solutions $c=\pm1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to solve the congruence $(c-1)(c+1)\equiv 0\pmod{2^a}$, where $a\ge 3$. Note that $c$ must be odd, and that $c-1$ and $c+1$ are two consecutive even numbers.

Since $c-1$ and $c+1$ are consecutive even numbers, one of them is congruent to $2$ modulo $4$, and therefore only has one $2$ to contribute to the product.

Case 1: [$c+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$]  Since $2^a$ divides $(c-1)(c+1)$, $2^{a-1}$ must divide $c-1$. So $c\equiv 1\pmod{2^{a-1}}$, and therefore $c=1+k2^{a-1}$ for some integer $k$. If $k$ is even, then $s\equiv 1\pmod{2^a}$. If $k$ is odd then $c\equiv 1+2^{a-1}\pmod{2^{a}}$. 
It is clear that $c\equiv 1\pmod{2^a}$ and $c\equiv 1+2^{a-1}\pmod{2^a}$ *are* solutions.

Case 2: [$c-1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$] Then $2^{a-1}$ must divide $c+1$, and therefore $c=-1+k2^{a-1}$ for some integer $k$. If $k$ is even then $c\equiv -1+2^{a-1}\pmod{2^{a}}$, and if $k$ is odd then $c\equiv -1+2^{a-1}\pmod{2^{a}}$.

If $a\ge 3$, then the four solutions are distinct modulo $2^a$.

Answer (score 0):

Extended hints (prove/validate/justify the steps):

- $c^2-1=(c-1)(c+1)$
- We want the product $mn$ with $m=c+1$, $n=c-1$ to be divisible by $2^a$. For that to happen we must have an integer $k, 0\le k\le a,$ such that $2^k\mid m$ and $2^{a-k}\mid n$.
- Because $c+1$ and $c-1$ differ from each other by two, at most one of them can be divisible by four.
- Therefore in the second bullet the parameter $k$ must be one of $0,1,a-1,a$. The in-between range of choices does not work.
- The given list of four possibilities comes out of this.

Comment: My search-fu is weak today. This **has to** be a duplicate, but I couldn't locate one. I will delete the answer, when we find a suitable mother thread.

Comment: For example all the questions about the stucture of the group of units $\Bbb{Z}_{2^n}^*$ of the ring of integers modulo $2^n$ implicitly have this as well. I'm not sure that the OP will appreciate those, though.